# Create a session secret - Python - Google Drive SDK

Tags: python-2.7, google-drive-api

Using: Windows 7, Python 2.7

Code:
Dr Edit - Google's example for creating a new file in Google Drive

[Dr Edit Using Python with Google Drive SDK](https://github.com/googledrive/dredit/blob/master/python/README.md)

The README instructions state:

> Create a session secret, which should be at least 64 bytes of random
> characters, for example with

```
python -c "import os; print os.urandom(64)" > session.secret
```

I have no idea how to run this command line.  I've tried to run it in the Windows Command Prompt.  I've tried to run it in Python Shell.  I've tried to run it in the Python Commmand Line.  SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Is this README doc correct?  Is it outdated?  Am I doing something wrong?  Is this a line of code that is supposed to be part of a python program?  What is the -c for?

I just realized the the python -c is probably just notation to indicate that the user should use the python command line to enter what follows.

So I entered:

```
import os

print os.urandom(64)
```

And a string of special characters were printed:

> ﾀAËDkæ4ÃZ﾿ﾇTﾂUﾙﾋLﾟé-ﾂؓﾙﾄ0ﾰ'Ënﾰô#ߝUíèRKRüÏ*'ﾲﾤﾔﾅ%ÿëﾨÄÓò&

There is probably supposed to be a session.secret object?  file?  variable?  that the string of special characters get written to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to learn the Python Print function.

- You can read and write files in Python without importing a library.
- The Open() function in Python will open a file, **OR** create a new file
- There are four modes to open (create) a file
- 'r' read only
- 'w' write only
- 'a' append
- 'r+' both reading and writing

This will create a new text file named "daSecretCode" if there wasn't one already.  NOTE: The file gets created in the directory from where the .py module was run from.

```
daNewFile = open("daSecretCode.txt", "w")
```

Write content to file:

```
daNewFile.write("oerjfwi456745oetr78u9f9oirhiwurhkwejr")
```

Close the file:

```
daNewfile.close()
```

Write a new session secret to a new file:

```
import os
daSecretCode = repr(os.urandom(64))
daNewfile = open("daSecretCode.txt", "w")
daNewfile.write(daSecretCode)
daNewfile.close()
```

I'm not sure how I could format the content to look like the original output.  The characters get formatted into something else.